# how to call stored procedure from ASP.NET Core and serve it in Angular 7? Need Step wise solution

Tags: angular7, aspnetboilerplate

Company asked me to implement ASP.NET Zero web portal for our solutions. ASP.NET Zero based on ASP.NET Core + Angular Js. I am learning it since last 15 days. Now I wanted to know how to call stored procedures from ASP.NET Core and serve it in Angular.
Can Anyone explain with simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to choose in order to call a SP from your Application Services regardless of SPA or MPA solution.

1. You can use Abp.Dapper nugget package
2. You can create a method in your EF DbContext which let you call any stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Repository` class for your desired entity on Entity Framework part. It should inherit from `RepositoryBase` class and implement interface for related entity. Then add a method for calling a stored procedure.

For example:

```
public class UserProfileRepository : CommEngineRepositoryBase<UserProfile, int>, IUserProfileRepository
{
    public UserProfileRepository(IDbContextProvider<CommEngineDbContext> dbContextProvider, IActiveTransactionProvider transactionProvider)
        : base(dbContextProvider, transactionProvider)
    {
    }

    public async Task<List<(string, int)>> GetCategoryAnalyticsForUser(int tenantId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, long? userId)
    {
        EnsureConnectionOpen();

        var nullableUserId = userId.HasValue ? (object)userId : DBNull.Value;

        var output = new List<(string, int)>();

        try
        {
            using (var command = CreateCommand("GetCategoryAnalyticsForUser",
                                               CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                               new SqlParameter[]
                                                   {
                                                   new SqlParameter("@TenantId", tenantId),
                                                   new SqlParameter("@UserId", nullableUserId),
                                                   new SqlParameter("@StartDate", startDate),
                                                   new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate)
                                                   }
           ))
            {
                using (var dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        string tag = dataReader["Tag"].ToString();
                        int.TryParse(dataReader["Count"].ToString(), out int count);
                        output.Add((tag, count));
                    }
                }
            }

            return output;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.Message, ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseDbConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

You call this from `IUserProfileRepository` interface.

Enjoy!